# How to set an Array that references variables, that also references variables

Tags: arrays, bash, function, variables, sh

Random Variables

```
VARA=('blah')
VARB=('blah2')
VARC=('blah3' 'alt_blah3')

MASTERVAR=${VARA}${VARB}${VARC[0]}
ULTIMATEVAR=${VARA}${VARB}${VARC[1]}
```

What I want: An Array that references MASTERVAR and ULTIMATEVAR.

```
ULTIMATEMASTERVAR=(${MASTERVAR} ${ULTIMATEVAR})
```

What I've tried.

```
ULTIMATEMASTERVAR=('${MASTERVAR}' '${ULTIMATEVAR}')
ULTIMATEMASTERVAR=(${!MASTERVAR} ${!ULTIMATEVAR})
```

Wanted Result:

```
echo ${ULTIMATEMASTERVAR[0]}
```

Which prints out

```
blahblah2blah3
```

Comment: If you are just going to use `${VARA}` and not `${VARA[0]}`, you don't need to use parentheses to assign to it: `VARA='blah'`.

Answer (score 0):

How to refer to other variables in an array:

```
$ foo=(abc)
$ bar=(def)
$ all=(foo bar)
$ echo "${all[0]}"
foo
$ echo "${!all[0]}"
abc
```

Loop through `all` to get the first element of each of them.